# Quartz .net job is not executing

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've created an ASP.NET MVC website. Then I've created a class library named Site.Scheduler where I wanted to put all my triggers and jobs.

I've created a simple job for testing purposes

```
public class CurrencyRatesJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IBudgetsRepository budgetsRepository;

    public CurrencyRatesJob(IBudgetsRepository budgetsRepository)
    {
        this.budgetsRepository = budgetsRepository;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var budgets = new BudgetsDTO();
            var user = new UserDTO();

            budgets.Sum = 1;
            budgets.Name = "Quartz";
            user.Email = "email@g.com";

            budgetsRepository.InsertBudget(budgets, user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Quartz.JobExecutionException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and a Job Scheduler

```
public class CurrencyRatesJobScheduler
{
    public static void GetCurrencyRates()
    {
        try
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CurrencyRatesJob>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule
                    (s =>
                        s.WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever()
                    )
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To start the scheduler when application starts, I've added the following in Global.asax.cs

```
CurrencyRatesJobScheduler.GetCurrencyRates();
```

So after all that, I was expecting the job to execute every 10 seconds and insert all that info in the DB, but it doesn't do anything and I get no errors either.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

**EDIT:**

So I've created all the necessary tables (executed the script from Quartz.NET) and I've added a new App.config file in my class library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MyQuartzScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="instance_one" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="1" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Server=(local);Database=My.Database;UID=User;PWD=Password" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Still no luck. Besides that, no triggers or jobs were stored in the DB.

Comment: What do you expect `catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }` to do?

Comment: I was thinking it my be an error when I scheduled the job. I'm using it when I debug.

Comment: Well, the thing is, it catches the error, makes a string out of it, but it doesn't do anything with this string. So what actually happens... it silences any error within the `try {}` statement.

Comment: See edit for config section

Answer (score 6):

You need to call

```
  scheduler.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that stands out, you haven't started `scheduler`. So quartz is not running.

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.Start();
```

After starting it the server will scan the db for job details/triggers and proceed accordingly.

However, you also want to add proper identities to your job detail/trigger. These are needed for quartz to create primary keys, otherwise you will get a `SchedulerException`.

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CurrencyRatesJob>()
                           .WithIdentity("currencyJob", "group1")
                           .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .StartNow()
                   .WithIdentity("currencyJob", "group1")
                   .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
                   .Build();
```

Regarding your config file, you need to declare an appropriate quartz section and add the settings there (by default this is where `StdSchedulerFactory` looks to create properties)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </configSections>

  <quartz>
     <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MyQuartzScheduler" />
     <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />
      ...
  </quartz>   
</configuration>
```

Comment: It still doesn't run the job. I was thinking right now, I didn't do any configuration for quartz to tell him the number of threads or the job store type.  I've read on Quartz .net site that "Quartz.NET comes with sane defaults".

Comment: There are a number of config settings that need to be set. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473408/configuring-quartz-net-with-sql-server-adojobstore) for more info

Comment: Tried the config thing. Still doesn't work. Now I get some messages from that config saying that "Coult not find schema information for element quartz" and many more. Should I edit the job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd to add those elements?

Comment: @MarianEne if you're using RAMJobStore yes. RAMJobStore means you store your job information in the quartz.xml file. You will also need to change your config file as mentioned [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigRAMJobStore). I thought you were using ADOJobStore (jobs are stored in database) because you mentioned database in your question

Comment: I am using ADOJobStore, but I'm getting those messages anyway. I still don't understand why it isn't working, despite the fact that I don't get any errors. Neither triggers or job details are saved in QRTZ_xxx tables .

Comment: @MarianEne That's weird. I'm using pretty much the same code and it works on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing the same issue. i fixed the issue by placing config information in the app.config in the consuming application. As Class Library does not capable of running independently. It should be referenced by another app maybe console or web site. we need to place all config items in the consuming application this may be help. cheers. happy sharing