# Where do I put the code to configure AdoJobStore for Quartz.NET?

Tags: ado.net, quartz.net

Apologies that I'm quite new to C# in general.

I'm trying to create a desktop app using Quartz.NET, and it needs to include an AdoJobStore. The documentation on AdoJobStore from Quarz-Scheduler.net [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/job-stores.html#ado-net-job-store-adojobstore) provides snippets of code (e.g. `quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz` under "Configuring Quartz to use JobStoreTx"), but as a beginner I have no idea where I'm supposed to put this code.

I've seen in other sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473408/configuring-quartz-net-with-sql-server-adojobstore) or [here](https://github.com/xuke353/AdmBoots/blob/88fda26e7361ea663fbaf2ae51201868d8d9d6a0/AdmBoots.Api/Extensions/QuartzStartup.cs#L33), this code is part of a NameValueCollection that is passed as props into a StdSchedulerFactory object. However, according to the latest documentation [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/using-quartz.html), a SchedulerFactory object is initiated using `Services.GetRequiredService<ISchedulerFactory>()`, so now I'm really confused.

The only other places I can think of are under `AddQuartz` or in app.config.

Can someone else please help? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation hasn't been keeping up with development. Please check the ASP.NET Core example and its Startup.cs: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/v3.6.3/src/Quartz.Examples.AspNetCore for DI configuration, there are also other example projects.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoLahma. Are you a regular user of Quartz? Do you know off the top of your head example desktop projects?

Comment: You can utilize SchedulerBuilder to get similar API configuration.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoLahma, it's great to hear from one of the contributors. I'm still not sure what the SchedulerBuilder is for. When do I need it? I see it here in [Quick Start](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#nuget-package), but not elsewhere in the tutorial series. Or does that include `CronScheduleBuilder`?

Comment: Hello @MarkoLahma. Can I make a suggestion? On the page [Using Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/using-quartz.html#configure-program-cs), you have code which contains a variable called `builder`, which I think is misleading as it is an initialised IHost object, and not a HostBuilder object. So, it should probably be `host`, as is also the case in other sample code like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413002/whats-the-difference-between-these-ways-to-start-run-a-generic-host-in-asp-net). Thanks for hearing me out.